# How to use electron's app.getPath() to store data?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to store images on the users computer, so I figure it should be stored in users data folder, as described [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname).

> **`app.getPath(name)`**
>
> `name`. Returns String - A path to a special directory or file associated with name. On failure an Error is thrown. You can request the following paths by the name:
>
> - `home` User's home directory
> - `appData` Per-user application data directory, which by default points to:
>
>   %APPDATA% on Windows
>     $XDG_CONFIG_HOME or ~/.config on Linux
>     ~/Library/Application Support on macOS
> - `userData` The directory for storing your app's configuration files, which by default it is the appData directory appended with your app's name.
> - ...

This is what I think you're supposed to do:

```
const app = require('electron');
alert(app.getPath('userData'));
```

But I get "getPath is not a function". I am not sure where to put it. It does not work from my html file or the renderer file, and I'm not sure how to use it from the main file because that's not linked to the web page.

Comment: const app = require('electron').app I guess?

Comment: or perhaps `const {app} = require('electron')`

Comment: this is `const { remote } = require('electron')` and then `remote.app.getPath('userData')`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since the `remote` method is being considered deprecated, as shown [here](https://medium.com/@nornagon/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31), I'd suggest you do this:

```
const {app} = require('electron');
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined

Comment: @AlexeySh. This won't work if you call it from a renderer process. You need to create an ipc handler to send the data from your main process to a renderer process. Take a look at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Hrun but I did use niksmac's approach

Comment: No problem @AlexeySh. 

A quick heads up for you and other readers who might come across this thread in the future though: the remote module will be removed in electron 14, which means that this approach won't work anymore.

The remote module will be replaced by the @electron/remote module temporarily after that, but it will be eventually removed too (according to the [readme](https://github.com/electron/remote)).

So your best bet is to just write an ipc handler.

Comment: Reading this in 2024 where we consider security an issue, the way to go is to do all Electron API operations in the preload scripts and call it from the renderer, For more information and examples, read more here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload 
In short, you define all Electron and other node operations in preload script/API and it exposes only "secured functions" to the renderer. Preload exposes its api like
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  getUserDataPath: () => app.getPath('userData'),
}
Consume renderer: window.api.getUserDataPath();

Answer (score 19):

`remote` is considered dangerous.

`app.getPath` will be always available in `main` process.

Here is how to do it in renderer process without using `remote` (electron 7+)

Basically you have to use `invoke` in renderer.

in `main`

```js
ipcMain.handle('read-user-data', async (event, fileName) => {
  const path = electron.app.getPath('userData');
  const buf = await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}/${fileName}`));
  return buf;
})
```

in `renderer`

```js
ipcRenderer.invoke('read-user-data', 'fileName.txt').then(
  result => doSomething()
);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I use when I need to switch between dev and release

```
const electron = require('electron');
export const userDataPath = (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath(
  'userData'
);
```

Comment: This is better than stackers' answer imo because this also works when the remote didn't get initialized yet.

Comment: seems like this approach is not about dev and release, but about main and renderer processes. using short-circuit evaluation make possible to use this code both in main and renderer processes.
so, is this answer differ from @RedSandman's answer?

Answer (score 7):

Another way to prevent the error "getPath is not a function" is to make the code work both in the renderer process and the main process:

```
const electron = require('electron');

const configDir =  (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath('userData');
console.log(configDir);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with `app.getPath('userData')` to save/load config files, etc and ended up using OS specific env vars in the meantime:

```
const getAppBasePath = () => {
        //dev
    if (process.env.RUN_ENV === 'development') return './'

    if (!process.platform || !['win32', 'darwin'].includes(process.platform)) {
        console.error(`Unsupported OS: ${process.platform}`)
        return './'
    }
        //prod
    if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
        console.log('Mac OS detected')
        return `/Users/${process.env.USER}/Library/Application\ Support/${YOUR_APP_NAME}/`
    } else if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        console.log('Windows OS detected')
        return `${process.env.LOCALAPPDATA}\\${YOUR_APP_NAME}\\`
    }
}
```

Comment: using electron v13.1.7

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna do it in renderer process
try this,it is work for me

```
// main.js

const electron = require('electron')

const electronRemote = process.type === 'browser' ? electron : 
require('@electron/remote')

const { app, ipcMain, Menu, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

const BrowserWindow = electronRemote.BrowserWindow

const isDev= require('electron-is-dev')

const { initialize, enable } = require('@electron/remote/main')

initialize()

let mainWindow

app.on('ready', ()=>{
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1024,
     height: 600,
     minWidth:600,
     webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true,
        contextIsolation: false
     }
   })
   enable(mainWindow.webContents)

})
```

render process

```
// render process
const { app } = window.require('@electron/remote')
const savedPath = app.getPath('userData')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Comment: the answer by zhang is actually better than most of the other answers.