# Write to file in "appData" in Electron. Where to add import { app } from "electron";?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am making my first Electron application. I am trying to save a text file to the appData folder (example `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming`). I know I need to add `import { app } from "electron";` somewhere but I am unsure where to place it.

In my `index.js` javascript I am writing the database settings that the user submits in his form to a text file. This is where I need to have the `appData` directory address.

```
// Write data to text file
var filepath = app.getPath("appData") 
var filename = "database_quick_image_forensics.txt"
var inp_data = inp_host + "|" + inp_username + "|" + inp_password + "|" + inp_database_name + "|" + inp_table_prefix;
write_to_file(filepath, filename, inp_data);
```

My entire code is below:

`./setup/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Setup</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->

        <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_webdesign/dark/dark.css" />
        <!-- // CSS -->


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../javascripts/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js');</script>
    <script src="../javascripts/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- //jQuery -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="./index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- //jQuery -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_single_column">
  <h1>Setup</h1>

<!-- Feedback -->
    <div id="feedback_div" class="success">
        <p id="feedback_p">Success</p>
    </div>
<!-- //Feedback -->

<!-- Database connection form -->

      <p>Host:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inp_host" id="inp_host" value="localhost" />
      </p>

      <p>Port:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inpport" id="inp_port" value="" />
      </p>

      <p>Username:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inp_username" id="inp_username" value="root" />
      </p>

      <p>Password:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inp_password" id="inp_password" />
      </p>

      <p>Database name:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inp_database_name" id="inp_database_name" value="quick" />
      </p>

      <p>Table prefix:<br />
      <input type="text" name="inp_table_prefix" id="inp_table_prefix" value="cf_" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <button id="form_connect_to_database_submit">Connect to database</button>
      </p>

<!-- //Database connection form -->
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

`./setup/index.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Action = On submit
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form_connect_to_database_submit").click( function() {
        // Feedback
        $('#feedback_div').show();
        $('#feedback_div').removeClass("success");
        $('#feedback_div').addClass("info");
        $('#feedback_p').text("Connecting!")

        // get all the inputs
        var inp_host = $("#inp_host"). val();
        var inp_username = $("#inp_username"). val();
        var inp_password = $("#inp_password"). val();
        var inp_database_name = $("#inp_database_name"). val();
        var inp_table_prefix = $("#inp_table_prefix"). val();

        // Test connection
        var connection_result = connect_to_database(inp_host, inp_username, inp_password, inp_database_name, inp_table_prefix);
        if(connection_result != "connection_ok"){
            // Connection Failed
            $('#feedback_div').removeClass("info");
            $('#feedback_div').addClass("error");
            $('#feedback_p').text(connection_result)
        }
        else{
            // Connection OK
            $('#feedback_div').removeClass("info");
            $('#feedback_div').addClass("success");
            $('#feedback_p').text("Connected")

            // Write data to text file
            var filepath = app.getPath("appData") 
            var filename = "database_quick_image_forensics.txt"
            var inp_data = inp_host + "|" + inp_username + "|" + inp_password + "|" + inp_database_name + "|" + inp_table_prefix;
            $('#feedback_p').text("Connected " + filepath)
            write_to_file(filepath, filename, inp_data);
    
            // Feedback
            $('#feedback_div').removeClass("info");
            $('#feedback_div').addClass("success");
            $('#feedback_p').text("Connected to")
        }



        
    });
    $('#inp_host').focus();
});


// Function connect to database
function connect_to_database(inp_host, inp_username, inp_password, inp_database_name, inp_table_prefix){
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    // Add the credentials to access your database
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : inp_host,
        user     : inp_username,
        password : null, // or the original password : 'apaswword'
        database : inp_database_name
    });

    // connect to mysql
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        // in case of error
        if(err){
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.fatal);
            return err.code;
        }
    });


    // Perform a query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cf_admin_liquidbase` LIMIT 10';
    connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Query succesfully executed", rows);
    });

    return "connection_ok";
} // connect_to_database




// Function write setup
function write_to_file(filepath, filename, inp_data){
    

    var fullpath = filepath + "\\" + filename;
    fs.writeFile(fullpath, inp_data, (err) => {
        // throws an error, you could also catch it here
        if (err) throw err;
        // success case, the file was saved
        console.log('Lyric saved!');
    });
} // write_to_file
```

`./main.js`:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')


// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win


function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
          }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
          // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
          // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
          // when you should delete the corresponding element.
          win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
          app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
          createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962333/840992

Comment: @NoGrabbing I still dont know where to add the import

Comment: @Europa. Please check my answer. You are free to use this at Renderer or Main

Comment: Anyhow, check my answer

Comment: Was trying to make the detailed answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I need to add import { app } from "electron"; some where but I
> am unsure where to place it.

The [app](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md) module is always (in my experience) imported in your `main` process so you can control the applications lifecycle. However, if you want to use some of the `app` module functionality in your `renderer` process, you can import it there through the `remote` module ( as shown in the accepted answer to this question: [How to use electron's app.getPath() to store data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957479/how-to-use-electrons-app-getpath-to-store-data/47962333#47962333) )

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const app = remote.app;
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

The `main` and `renderer` processes are key concepts in `Electron` so I'd suggest reading up on those. The gist is that you have one `main` process – it has no visual representation and it is involved with the lifecycle of your app, creating and destroying `renderer` processes (like [BrowserWindows](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)), communication between renderer processes, etc.  – and you can have as many `renderer` processes as you need.

So if you want to read and write files you can do it in the `renderer` process as shown above – or you can do it in the `main` process. In the latter case, if a `renderer` process wants to save a file, it can message the `main` process through [IPC](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/ipc-communication.html), sending the data to be saved.

Which way you do it is an architectural choice.

Answer (score 0):

To get the app path at your **main process**. Then use this code at your main.js

```
switch(process.platform) {
    case 'darwin': {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, 'Library', 'Application Support', ...);
    }
    case 'win32': {
      return path.join(process.env.APPDATA, ...);
    }
    case 'linux': {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, ...);
    }
}
```

And going to get the path from the **renderer** then use this code at your **renderer**

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const app = remote.app;
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

But to use require at your renderer, please make sure **nodeintegration** is true.

If I were you, I was going to get the app path at **main process** and  store the file at **main process** as well.
Hence, importing many dependencies at **renderer process** is not a good choice. 
The **renderer process** mainly takes care of showing your app in the Chromium browser.

So to make this operation at **main process**. Use this

at your main.js

```
  const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
  const appPath = () => {
    switch(process.platform) {
      case 'darwin': {
        return path.join(process.env.HOME, 'Library', 'Application Support');
      }
      case 'win32': {
        return process.env.APPDATA;
      }
      case 'linux': {
        return process.env.HOME;
      }
    }
  }

  const writeToFile = (fileName, inData) => {
      const fullPath = path.join(appPath(), "\\", fileName);
      fs.writeFile(fullPath, inData, (err) => {
        // throws an error, you could also catch it here
        if (err) throw err;
        // success case, the file was saved
        console.log('Lyric saved!');
    });
  } // write_to_file

  ipcMain.on('WRITE_TEXT', async (event, arg) => {
    writeToFile(arg.fileName, arg.inData)
  });
```

At your renderer process add this code.

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
ipcRenderer.sendSync('WRITE_TEXT',{fileName, inData})
```

As you can see, at **renderer process**, this is sending the `inp_data` to your **main process** through 'WRITE_TEXT' **IPC channel**.

One more thing here, at your code. You are connecting your DB at your renderer and it's possible but this is not a right choice. Please think while you are having the several renderer. You should move this to main process too.